# Ethereum address -> private key correspondance

Tags: solidity, tokens, addresses, public-key

It is known that Ethereum addresses are generated by hashing the pubkey (ref. [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)). However, I'm not certain that a single pubkey corresponds to a single address.

**Use case**

I would like to implement a schema of token exchanges where a user can send a single token only once (a kind of voting). The user generates a keypair and derives an address from the public key. The user then discards the keypair. I would like to be sure that a voter can't generate another address using the same keypair causing me to count his token twice.

Comment: Related: [Is each Ethereum address shared by (theoretically) 2 ** 96 private keys?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/is-each-ethereum-address-shared-by-theoretically-2-96-private-keys?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're asking "Can the same address come from two different private keys?" (Yes, but it's hard to find such a collision.) or "Can the same private key produce two different addresses?" (No.) or maybe "Can the same public key produce two different addresses?" (No for the same reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments:

> Could you clarify whether you're asking "Can the same address come from two different private keys?" (Yes, but it's hard to find such a collision.) or "Can the same private key produce two different addresses?" (No.) or maybe "Can the same public key produce two different addresses?" (No for the same reason.) – smarx

answers my question perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you solve the "double spending" problem simply by keeping balances, as with the `balances` variable in a standard contract?

Comment: The idea is as follows: there will be a contract that will mint the tokens. The number of voters is well known (n - the total number of voters). Any new user is able to withdraw a single token from the mint. The withdrawal history can be tracked by keeping track if an address has withdrawn it's token from the mint. If an address tries to withdraw a token from the mint twice, it will fail.

However, this only makes sense if only a single address can be derived from a public key. A balance variable can't solve this issue if the opposite is true.