# Identical account hash in mainnet and testnets

Tags: accounts, testnets, account-generation

The other day I was checking on my two ethereum accounts (they are 4+ years old).

There was a small "!" in etherscan.io that caught my eye: it alerted me that my first mainnet account hash is found also in ropsten *and* kovan testnets.  My second mainnet account was replicated only in ropsten.

*I got ...t scared!*

Same account hash means that it has been generated from the same public key as mine, while that in turn has been generated from the same **private** key that is mine (see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/is-each-ethereum-address-shared-by-theoretically-2-96-private-keys))

Investigating more on the replicated account in ropsten, I saw that it had some "airdrop" tokens in there.

So has someone copied parts of mainnet into ropsten and then that same pumpkin fairy has airdropped me some tokens?  I would have appreciated him/her not doing so & not giving me this halloween scare-time.

An explanation of what is going on would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean public key/address -> since wallets are generating private/public keys in a deterministic way, in general based on a seed phrase (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/75), *irregardless of the chain*, your address is considered as "active" for actors having such a need.

Airdropped token, outside of active project rewarding their users, are mostly projects trying to artificially inflate their holders number (some aggregators like CG/CMC requires a threshold) or scam (requiring to "unlock" transfer via a fee on their frontend, for instance).

In other word, seeing your address **receiving** airdrops on a chain you never used isn't a sign that your private key is compromised (of course, use a cold wallet/ledger, etc)