# How can I generate EOA address on testnet using JavaScript without access to ETH node?

Tags: testnets, addresses, ropsten, eoa

I just started Ethereum. I found how to generate an address by using JavaScript like below. I need an address for testnet. I'm using Ropsten testnet. In bitcoin, I can generate from pubkey to both mainnet address and testnet address. Does Ethereum have the same rule?

```
var bip39 = require('bip39');
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey')

var mnemonic = 'xxx xxx xxx...';
var password = '';
var masterseed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic, password);
var hdnode = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(masterseed);

var getKeyPair = function(hdnode){
    return {
        "address" : hdnode.getWallet().getAddressString(),
        "private" : hdnode.getWallet().getPrivateKeyString(),
        "public" : hdnode.getWallet().getPublicKeyString(),
    }
}

// cointype=60=eth
// m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
console.log(getKeyPair(hdnode.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0"))) // { address: '0xbc0c53d89b2fe10d1d140665bd94b3d926f4a790', private: 'xxx', public: 'xxx' }
```

---

Update 1

Seems the address format of mainnet and testnet are same.

> There is no way to verify if an address belongs to a particular network - they are all valid for every Ethereum network.

[Are addresses between different networks (testnet) interchangeable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/are-addresses-between-different-networks-testnet-interchangeable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike bitcoin, ethereum eoa address does not distinguish between mainnet and testnet.

> There is no way to verify if an address belongs to a particular network - they are all valid for every Ethereum network.

[Are addresses between different networks (testnet) interchangeable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/are-addresses-between-different-networks-testnet-interchangeable)